# How to create userform table to consist of conditional formatting?

Tags: excel, vba, userform, conditional-formatting

So I have a table with conditional formatting already setup (attached). 
The values are being highlighted in red when greater than +/-35mm for each constituent separately (dE, dN, dH).

what I'm looking for is to create a userform so the user don't have to navigate to manage rules, instead the threshold for each constituent can be changed directly from the userform.

attached is also a photo of what I need [Needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xQp3.jpg)

All help greatly appreciated.

[image: Table]
[conditional_formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JW9DD.jpg)

Comment: What is your question? You didn't ask one. Please read [ask].

Comment: Use conditional formatting with the same setup, but pointing to a cell for your value and have the userform read/write to that cell.

Comment: I created a table in Microsoft Visual Basic (picture attached). Can you please advise where should I enter the code (and what)?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what you are asking for but my understanding is you want to click on that record and edit it on a user form and you have your spread sheet already formatted.Use this code to achieve that.

place this code behind your sheet in VBA editor(the one with the data to be manipulated)

```
     Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
     '##################################################
     '# Intercept a double click in the record area    #
      '# and open the edit form 36                        #
      '##################################################

If Target.Column > 65 Or Target.Row < 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

Cancel = True
EditRecord

End Sub
```

and place this one on a module

```
  Sub EditRecord()
   Dim CurRow As Integer, CurCol As Integer, intCount1 As Long
   Dim RecordEntry
   Dim iRow As Long

   CurRow = ActiveCell.Row


   Range("A" & CurRow).Select
' check if empty row - if so call new record
   With ActiveCell
     If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ' check empty rows and create new record goto_empty_row
        UserForm1.Show
        Exit Sub
     End If
   End With

   ' edit existing record - populate form
   With UserForm1
     .TextBox1.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0)
     .TextBox2.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1)
     .TextBox3.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2)

 .Show
  End With
  End Sub
```

and then this on your user form

```
     Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  Dim iRow As Long
   Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet2") 'name of the Sheet
     'copy the data to the spread sheet
      ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = Me.TextBox1.Value
     ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value = Me.TextBox2.Value
    ws.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value = Me.TextBox3.Value

       End Sub
```

Comment: the userform window pops up when double clicked on the sheet, but it doesn't do anything.

Comment: I wanted to change the range (edit the rule description) in the userform instead of highlighting each column and going to edit formatting rule. picture attached with edit format rule.

Comment: I attached a photo of what I need, maybe that will be easier to understand what I mean. Thanks